# Contact form not sending full message?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm new here, and I heard this was an excellent community to ask coding questions. I just recently rebuilt my portfolio site, and I'm seem to be stuck making my contact page to work.

- [Contact Page On The Server](http://jbrittendesignvfx.com/contact.html)

Basically I set it up to make sure the form sends correctly to the right address, but when the email is sent, I keep seeing this text in the body of the email" 

From:

E-Mail:

Message:

Not mention that it sends the email to my personal one, instead. I'm not very well versed in php yet, so I was wondering what I could change around in the contactengine.php file

Edit, here's the [contactengine.php](http://pastebin.com/3CA3z6jK) file

Comment: unassigned or mismatch in form variables. could be many other reasons, not knowing without your full code for form and handler php. Just the link you gave, is not enough.

Comment: I put up the source code in the edit

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are capturing variables correctly i.e.

`$_POST['Name']`, `$_POST['Email']` and `$_POST['Message']`

Then make sure if these are being concatenated properly with you email body. If you can post contactengine.php code, that would be helpful in sorting your problem.